# ID selector with JavaScript & JQuery not working with show or visible style

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, visibility, show

My essential problem is that I am trying to select individual ID elements - either with JQuery or vanilla JavaScript - and show them at different time points, like an online powerpoint show of results. Of note, though the code below will be with JQuery, I have tried JavaScript, via document.getElementById and document.querySelector and setting the style.visibility to visible and even in JQuery, tried $("[id='']").show() and put these into the Console, yet nothing shows! The same code works for HTML elements not subsumed under a div element - is there something there I am missing? But then why does hiding the element work? Why would show no longer work? I have also tried changing up whether it's loading in JQuery from a source or an external script nearby, and putting the JavaScript in the head vs. the body (in case, despite the DOM loading condition, the code was referencing something it hadn't yet identified). Neither changed things.

So, the function works just fine - the Next and Previous buttons will click through the slide numbers appropriately. Clicking the nav item titled phase I (or phase II - I commented that one out since I didn't include the rest of the HTML that isn't working w/ phase1q2, phase1q3, etc.) works fine. What is not working is actually showing these HTML elements at the key time points, and as I said earlier, it wasn't working in the Console, nor with vanilla JavaScript. I tried using the code for the specific p element ids, like phase1intro and phase1q1student. I tried removing the div elements w/ the row/justify-content/pad and just using p elements. Without the hideAll function, everything shows on the paragraph, which suggested no HTML issue. No errors show up in the Console, either. When I run JQuery in the console, it says "jQuery.fn.init [div#phase1intro.row.justify-content-start.pad75.mainfont, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]". I.e., no error. Same with style.visibility. I've been working on this for hours, and I'm at a loss - what am I missing here? Is it the div + p? Do I need to be targeted, despite using an ID selector? Does every p element need its own id and I have to select them all individually to show? That's what I've done in other code, where this works fine - but that seems really wasteful code-wise!

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var Phase = 3;

  function hideAll() {
    $("#studypurpose").hide();
    $("#phase1all").hide();
    $("#phase2all").hide();
    $("#ViewStudy").hide();
    $("#PrevButton").hide();
    $("#NextButton").hide();
  }

  hideAll();

  $("a[href='#phase1']").click(function() {
    slideNum = 0;
    Phase = 1;
    hideAll();
    $("#preregistration").hide();
    $("#phase1intro").show();
    $("#phase1groups").show();
    $("#ViewStudy").show();
  });

  $("a[href='#phase2']").click(function() {
    slideNum = 0;
    Phase = 2;
    hideAll();
    $("#preregistration").hide();
    $("#phase2intro").show();
    $("#phase2groups").show();
    $("#ViewStudy").show();
  });

  var slideNum = 0;
  var maxNum = 5;

  $("#NextButton").on('click', function() {
    slideNum = slideNum + 1;
    moveShow(slideNum);
  });

  $("#ViewStudy").on('click', function() {
    $("#ViewStudy").hide();
    $("#NextButton").show();
    moveShow(slideNum);
  });

  $("#PrevButton").on('click', function() {
    slideNum = slideNum - 1;
    moveShow(slideNum);
  });

  function moveShow(slideNum) {
    if (slideNum == 0) {
      if (Phase == 1) {
        $("#phase1q1").show();
      } else {
        $("#phase2q1").show();
      }

      $("#NextButton").show();
      $("#PrevButton").hide();
    } else if (slideNum == 1) {
      if (Phase == 1) {
        $("#phase1q2").show();
      } else {
        $("#phase2q2").show();
      }

      $("#PrevButton").show();
    } else if (slideNum == 2) {
      if (Phase == 1) {
        $("#phase1q3").show();
      } else {
        $("#phase2q3").show();
      }
    } else if (slideNum == 3) {
      if (Phase == 1) {
        $("#phase1q4").show();
      } else {
        $("#phase2q4").show();
      }
    } else if (slideNum == 4) {
      if (Phase == 1) {
        $("#phase1q5").show();
      } else {
        $("#phase2appendix").show();
      }
    } else if (slideNum == 5) {
      if (Phase == 1) {
        $("#phase1appendix").show();
        $('#phase1end').show();
      }
    }

    if (slideNum == 0) {
      $("#NextButton").show();
    } else if (slideNum < maxNum) {
      $("#NextButton").show();
      $("#PrevButton").show();
    } else {
      $("#NextButton").hide();
      $('#phase1end').html('Thank you for checking out the efficacy study results!');
      $('#phase2appendix').html('Thank you for checking out the efficacy study results!');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.image {
  min-height: 100vh
}

.bg-image {
  background-image: url('...');
  no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


/*font styling*/

.headfont {
  font-family: "Cabin";
}

.mainfont {
  font-family: "Hind Siliguri";
}


/*font awesome icon styling*/

.fa-bars {
  color: #3479B2;
}

.fa-asterisk {
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
  color: gray;
}

.scrollstyle {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  float: right;
}

.fa-li,
.fa-angle-up {
  color: #278652;
}

.relpos {
  position: relative;
}

.float-l {
  float: left;
}

.float-r {
  float: right;
}

.float-c {
  float: center;
}


/*links and button styling*/

.copy-link,
.copy-link:link {
  color: #3479B2;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.copy-link:hover,
.copy-link:active,
.copy-link:focus,
.copy-link:visited {
  color: #B8367E;
  transition: color .15s ease-in;
}

.bttn,
.bttn:focus,
.bttn:visited,
.bttn:active {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*colors*/

.white {
  color: #fff
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: #3479B2
}


/* padding */

.pv2 {
  padding-top: .5rem;
  padding-bottom: .5rem
}

.pad1 {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.pad75 {
  padding: 0.75rem;
}

.pad-l1 {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.pad-b75 {
  padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

.pad-t75 {
  padding-top: 0.75rem;
}

.pad-t125 {
  padding-top: 1.25rem;
}

.pad-lr {
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
}


/*navbar styling*/

.topnav .nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3479B2;
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid transparent;
}

.topnav .nav-link:hover {
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid #3479B2;
}

.topnav .nav-link:active {
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid #3479B2;
}

.navbar .dropdown-toggle {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-link-child,
.nav-link-child:hover {
  color: white;
}

.nav-link-child {
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

.nav-pad {
  padding-top: 2rem!important;
  padding-bottom: 4rem!important;
}

.nav-link:active,
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&family=Hind+Siliguri:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="d-none d-lg-flex col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 bg-image image"></div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-7 col-xl-7">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div class="col-lg-9 mx-auto">
            <nav class="navbar-nav navbar-expand-lg nav-pad headfont" role="navigation">
              <div class="navbar-header d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-none">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                                        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto topnav" role="navigation">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html" target="_self" role="link">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#phase1" target="_self">Experiment</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#phase2" target="_self">Classrooms</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
            <h1 class="d-none d-sm-block display-4 headfont">Title OK</h1>
            <h4 class="display-6 mainfont"><em>Question OK</em></h4>
            <div class="row justify-content-start pad75 mainfont" id="intro">
              <p>Also OK</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-start pad75 mainfont" id="preregistration">
              <p>Also OK - and this will "hide" when I click Phase I from the navbar.</p>
            </div>
            <section id="studypurpose">
              <div class="row justify-content-start pad75 mainfont" id="phase1intro">
                <p>This doesn't show</p>
              </div>
              <div class="row justify-content-start pad75 mainfont" id="phase2intro">
                <p>This doesn't show</p>
              </div>
              <div class="row justify-content-start pad75 mainfont" id="phase1groups">
                <p>This doesn't show</p>
              </div>
              <div class="row justify-content-start pad75 mainfont" id="phase2groups">
                <p>Nope, doesn't show</p>
              </div>
            </section>
            <section>
              <div id="phase1all">
                <div id="phase1q1">
                  <h4 class="display-6 mainfont" id="phase1q1header"><em>No show</em></h4>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75" id="phase1q1student">No show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75" id="phase1q1dash">No show</p>
                  <p class="row justify-content-start pad75" id="phase1q1concl">No show</p>
                </div>
                <div id="phase1q2">
                  <h4 class="display-6 mainfont"><em>no show?</em></h4>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">no show.</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">no show.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="phase1q3">
                  <h4 class="display-6 mainfont"><em>why?</em></h4>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">no show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75"> nope.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="phase1q4">
                  <h4 class="display-6 mainfont"><em>nope?</em></h4>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">Nope.</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">Nope.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="phase1q5">
                  <h4 class="display-6 mainfont"><em>Was our study manipulation effective?</em></h4>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="phase1appendix">
                  <h4 class="display-6 mainfont"><em>Appendix: Method</em></h4>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75"><u>Participants</u>: No show.</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75"><u>Task</u>: No show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show.</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75"><u>Manipulation Checks</u>: No show</p>
                </div>
                <p id="phase1end" class="justify-content-start pad75"></p>
              </div>
            </section>
            <section>
              <div id="phase2all">
                <div id="phase2q1">
                  <h4 class="display-6 mainfont"><em>No show</em></h4>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                </div>
                <div id="phase2q2">
                  <h4 class="display-6 mainfont"><em>No show</em></h4>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                </div>
                <div id="phase2q3">
                  <h4 class="display-6 mainfont"><em>No show</em></h4>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                </div>
                <div id="phase2q4">
                  <h4 class="display-6 mainfont"><em>No show</em></h4>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                </div>
                <div id="phase2appendix">
                  <h4 class="display-6 mainfont"><em>Appendix: Method</em></h4>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75"><u>Participants</u>: No show.</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75"><u>Task</u>: No show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                  <p class="justify-content-start pad75">No show</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
            <button id="NextButton" class="bttn pv2 white bg-blue rounded mainfont relpos float-r">Next </button>
            <button id="ViewStudy" class="bttn pv2 white bg-blue rounded mainfont relpos float-c">View Study Results</button>
            <button id="PrevButton" class="bttn pv2 white bg-blue rounded mainfont relpos float-l"> Previous</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's not a [mcve] and can you please add some [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to this block of text.

Comment: Using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` on the editor toolbar) would go a long way toward making this a bit more legible. Note that snippets have a Tidy button in the interface that formats the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript accordingly.

Comment: As far as the question, you can select elements in many different ways, not just IDs (which must be unique to the document). For instance, if there are a group of elements that logically belong together, adding the same class name to all of them would allow you to select them all for showing/hiding.

Comment: My apologies - I am in the middle of fixing the formatting now. I thought about the class, but from what I could tell using vanilla JS + jquery, no matter how I was selecting the element, the show/style.visibility stuff wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  //variable assignment
  var Phase = 3;
  var slideNum = 0;
  var maxNum = 5;

  //the JS for the return to the top button
  $("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, "slow");
    return false;
  });

  $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({
    trigger: "hover"
  });

  //hiding various things that don't need to be seen at first
  function hideAll() {
    $("#phase1intro").addClass('d-none');
    $("#phase2intro").addClass('d-none');
    $("#homelink").removeClass('active');
    $("#phase1link").removeClass('active');
    $("#phase2link").removeClass('active');
    $("#preregistration").hide();
    $("#ViewStudy").hide();
    $("#PrevButton").hide();
    $("#NextButton").hide();
  }

  hideAll();
  $("#preregistration").show();
  $("#homelink").addClass('active');

  //only showing things relevant to either Phase I or Phase II
  $("a[href='#phase1']").click(function() {
    slideNum = 0;
    Phase = 1;
    maxNum = 6;
    hideAll();
    $("div.p2").addClass('d-none');
    $("#phase1link").addClass('active');
    $("#phase1intro").removeClass('d-none');
    $("#ViewStudy").show();
  });

  $("a[href='#phase2']").click(function() {
    slideNum = 0;
    Phase = 2;
    maxNum = 5;
    hideAll();
    $("div.p1").addClass('d-none');
    $("#phase2link").addClass('active');
    $("#phase2intro").removeClass('d-none');
    $("#ViewStudy").show();
  });

  //Having the buttons to navigate through the slideshow
  $("#NextButton").on('click', function() {
    slideNum = slideNum + 1;
    moveShow(slideNum);
  });

  $("#ViewStudy").on('click', function() {
    $("#ViewStudy").hide();
    $("#NextButton").show();
    moveShow(slideNum);
  });

  $("#PrevButton").on('click', function() {
    $("#phase" + Phase + "q" + (slideNum + 1)).addClass('d-none');
    slideNum = slideNum - 1;
    moveShow(slideNum);
  });

  //the slideshow function - there are repeats to accomodation people using Prev/Next
  function moveShow(slideNum) {
    $('#phase1end').addClass('d-none');
    $('#phase2end').addClass('d-none');

    if (slideNum == 0) {
      $("#phase" + Phase + "q" + (slideNum + 1)).removeClass('d-none');
    } else if (slideNum < maxNum) {
      $("#phase" + Phase + "q" + (slideNum + 1)).removeClass('d-none');
      $("#phase" + Phase + "q" + (slideNum)).addClass('d-none');
    } else {
      if (Phase == 1) {
        $('#phase1end').removeClass('d-none');
      } else {
        $('#phase2end').removeClass('d-none');
      }
    }

    if (slideNum == 0) {
      $("#NextButton").show();
      $("#PrevButton").hide();
    } else if (slideNum < maxNum) {
      $("#NextButton").show();
      $("#PrevButton").show();
    } else {
      $("#NextButton").hide();
      $("#phase" + Phase + "q" + (slideNum)).addClass('d-none');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.image {
  min-height: 100vh
}

.bg-image {
  background-image: url('...');
  no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


/*font styling*/

.headfont {
  font-family: "Cabin";
}

.mainfont {
  font-family: "Hind Siliguri";
}


/*positioning*/

.relpos {
  position: relative;
}

.float-l {
  float: left;
}

.float-r {
  float: right;
}


/*links and button styling*/

.copy-link,
.copy-link:link {
  color: #3479B2;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.copy-link:hover,
.copy-link:active,
.copy-link:focus,
.copy-link:visited {
  color: #B8367E;
  transition: color .15s ease-in;
}

.bttn,
.bttn:focus,
.bttn:visited,
.bttn:active {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*colors*/

.white {
  color: #fff
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: #3479B2
}


/* padding */

.scrollstyle {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  float: right;
}

.pad1 {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.pad-end {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
  padding-top: 0.75rem;
}

.pv2 {
  padding-top: .5rem;
  padding-bottom: .5rem
}

p {
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  justify-content: start;
}

hr {
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}


/*navbar styling*/

.topnav .nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3479B2;
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid transparent;
}

.topnav .nav-link:hover {
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid #3479B2;
}

.topnav .nav-link:active {
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid #3479B2;
}

.nav-pad {
  padding-top: 2rem!important;
  padding-bottom: 2rem!important;
}

.nav-link:active,
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&family=Hind+Siliguri:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="d-none d-lg-flex col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 bg-image image" title="IPIP cover"></div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-7 col-xl-7">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div class="col-lg-9 mx-auto">
            <nav class="navbar-nav navbar-expand-lg nav-pad headfont" role="navigation">
              <div class="navbar-header d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-none">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                                        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto topnav" role="navigation">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="homelink" href="index.html" target="_self" role="link">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="phase1link" href="#phase1" target="_self">Experiment</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="phase2link" href="#phase2" target="_self">Classrooms</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
            <section class="mainfont">
              <h1 class="d-none d-sm-block display-4 headfont">Title</h1>
              <h4 class="display-6"><em>Main Q?</em></h4>
              <div class="row">
                <p id="intro">Text intro</p>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <p id="preregistration">prereg link text area.</p>
              </div>
              <section>
                <div class="row d-none" id="phase1intro">
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p>Text groups.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row d-none" id="phase2intro">
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p>Text groups.</p>
                </div>
              </section>
              <hr>
              <section>
                <div class="row d-none p1" id="phase1q1">
                  <h4 class="display-6"><em>Q1?</em></h4>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p>Texts.</p>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row d-none p1" id="phase1q2">
                  <h4 class="display-6"><em>Q2?</em></h4>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row d-none p1" id="phase1q3">
                  <h4 class="display-6"><em>Q3?</em></h4>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row d-none p1" id="phase1q4">
                  <h4 class="display-6"><em>Q4?</em></h4>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row d-none p1" id="phase1q5">
                  <h4 class="display-6"><em>Q5?</em></h4>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row d-none p1" id="phase1q6">
                  <h4 class="display-6"><em>Appendix: Method</em></h4>
                  <p><u>Participants</u>: Text.</p>
                  <p><u>Task</u>: Text.</p>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p><u>Manipulation Checks</u>: Text</p>
                </div>
                <p id="phase1end" class="d-none p1">Thank you for checking out the study results!</p>
              </section>
              <section>
                <div class="row d-none p2" id="phase2q1">
                  <h4 class="display-6"><em>Q1?</em></h4>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p>TExts.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row d-none p2" id="phase2q2">
                  <h4 class="display-6"><em>Q2</em></h4>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                  <p>Text.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row d-none p2" id="phase2q3">
                  <h4 class="display-6"><em>Q3?</em></h4>
                  <p>Text3.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row d-none p2" id="phase2q4">
                  <h4 class="display-6"><em>Q4?</em></h4>
                  <p>Text4.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row d-none p2" id="phase2q5">
                  <h4 class="display-6"><em>Appendix: Method</em></h4>
                  <p><u>Participants</u>: Text.</p>
                  <p><u>Task</u>: Text.</p>
                  <p>Text</p>
                  <p>Text</p>
                  <p>Text</p>
                  <p>Text</p>
                </div>
                <p id="phase2end p2" class="d-none">Thank you for checking out the study results!</p>
              </section>
              <section>
                <div class="d-lg-block d-xl-none scrollstyle pad1" id="top-scroll" aria-labelledby="scroll-to-top">
                  <a class="copy-link" href="#top" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" aria-labelledby="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Scroll to top">
                    <i class="fas fa-angle-up fa-3x bg-blue"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="row pad-end"></div>
              </section>
              <button id="NextButton" class="bttn pv2 white bg-blue rounded relpos float-r">Next </button>
              <button id="ViewStudy" class="bttn pv2 white bg-blue rounded relpos float-l">View Study Results</button>
              <button id="PrevButton" class="bttn pv2 white bg-blue rounded relpos float-l"> Previous</button>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The solution is that the parent CSS property is overriding the child div's CSS property. That's why even when I change the child div to 'show', it's still hidden (because the parent is still hidden and it's overriding the child). The bottom line is that there's no way to hide the parent div and selectively show the children. I either need to hide each child individually or reorganize so that all the content I want shown together is grouped together in the div. (The only thing not linked to above is the Font Awesome JS library, which I think is unique to person, so I'm avoiding that here. Oh, and the actual image in the left column.)

Comment: But why did the console throw error? I thought that was what's bothering you.

Comment: No, the console suggested code was fine: "When I run JQuery in the console, it says "jQuery.fn.init [div#phase1intro.row.justify-content-start.pad75.mainfont, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]". I.e., no error". It just wasn't actually *showing* the code. In retrospect, that should've been my cue that it was the structure. Will edit code above to show.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML I see missing end tag:

```
<h4 class="display-6 mainfont"><em>Question OK/em></h4>
```

should be

```
<h4 class="display-6 mainfont"><em>Question OK</em></h4>
```

Check your HTML for other unclosed tags, there could be more. Also your JS code is kind of messy, try formatting it, it will be easier for you and others.

Comment: yes, I'm sorry - this has come while I was adding stack snippets and then found that unclosed tag using the HTML validator.

Comment: There is a flag/close reason specifically for typos, if that is indeed the reason for the problems the user is presenting. Comment on the typos and flag/vote to close for the typo reason.

Comment: It is not the issue - I fixed all the formatting and the 'run code snippet' shows the issue exactly as described now. I'm sorry I didn't have the stack snippets correct at the start and caused these issues.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I thought that was the reason for the console error OP was getting, that's why I suggested it as a solution.